# Finite horizon SARSA Lambda

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Below is the pseudo-code for the SARSA(λ) algorithm -
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tqOM.png)

This code is for infinite horizon and I want the pseudo-code for finite horizon setting.
Please help.

I am unable to find any resources for finite horizon which is easily understandable.